# Wordpress : Update custom post type meta on focusout

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type

[Page custom post type comparercashback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP6gi.png)

I want to change the values of the meta to a custom post type named comparercashback on focusout with JQuery, any idea ? Thanks for your help.

Display post meta value :

```
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column',  'my_show_columns');

function my_show_columns($name) {
global $post;
switch ($name) {
    case 'Validée':
        $Validee = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'validee', true);
         echo "<input type='text' name='champ_validee' id='champ_validee' class='champ_validee' value='$Validee' />";
    break;
}
}
```

Update post meta value on focusout :

```
if (top.location.pathname === '/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=comparercashback/') {
    //alert('ok');

    jQuery( "#champ_validee" ).focusout(function() {

        <?php update_post_meta( $post->ID, $key = 'validee', $value = $('#champ_validee').val(); ); ?>
}
```